# jQuery how to store images source into a temporary memory and retrieve it later

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Please check below image.

[image]

When I will click on the hide images all the images show replaced with a static image and later when I will uncheck it it must show the original images now.

```
<div id="log_contents">    
    <span style="color:blue;"><b>Public chat</b> with <b>dragos123</b></span> <br><br>    
    <div class="chat-line"> 
        <span class="dialogue_time">  11:00:39 AM &nbsp;</span>
        <span style="background-color:FFF;">debasish:</span>
        <span style="background-color:FFF;"><img  style="cursor:pointer; max-height:80px;" src="http://localhost/myshowcam/files/stickers/msc-1427684408.gif" title=":party1"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-line"> 
        <span class="dialogue_time">  11:01:43 AM &nbsp;</span>
        <span style="background-color:ffff88;">pkk:</span>
        <span style="background-color:ffff88;">hiiiiiiiiiiiiii</span>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-line"> 
        <span class="dialogue_time">  11:02:03 AM &nbsp;</span>
        <span style="background-color:ffff88;">pkk:</span>
        <span style="background-color:ffff88;"><img  style="cursor:pointer; max-height:80px;" src="http://localhost/myshowcam/files/stickers/msc-1427684892.gif" title=":1min"></span>
    </div><div class="pagination" style=""></div>

</div>
```

Please give your valuable feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: so where is the rest of your code then?

Comment: We need much more information here.

Comment: `undo all` what's all here?

Comment: so you know how to change the image, and you want to know how to change it again?

Comment: Why people fool around instead of providing an answer ? Paradeepta , you can't do that. just save the old data vs data-* attribute. and then revert it to the old value.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Pradeepta. Please include what you've tried so far so people can help you. This is a site for helping people, not doing their work for them. You will probably find some hostility if you ask questions that show no attempt to achieve your goal on your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to hold the information regarding the original vlaue somewhere, otherwise, it would not be possible to revert this change.

I would change the initial code to something like

```
$("#log_contents").find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).data('img-org', $(this).attr('src'));
    $(this).attr('src', 'img/hide-image.gif');
});
```

and to reverse it, you just need to do the opposite

```
$("#log_contents").find('img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('img-org'));
});
```

Comment: damn you where faster...deleted my answer, as it was a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You could use some attribute to store original image source. It's not valid HTML, but it should work.

**Edit**: @Kami's answer with `data()` was better, so I've changed mine:

```js
function change(element){
  if($(element).prop('checked')){  
    $("img").each(function() {
      $(this).data("old-src", $(this).attr("src"));  
    });
    $('img').attr("src", 'http://img005.lazygirls.info/people/tamanna_bhatia/tamanna_bhatia_tamanna_latest_images_7_jpg_jpeg_image_1024_1226_pixels_scaled_76__qWkMn2nO.sized.jpg');
  } else {
    $("img").each(function() {
      $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("old-src"));
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png" /><br />
<img src="http://www.britishlegion.org.uk/ImageGen.ashx?width=800&image=/media/2019101/id23055-normandy-66th_-schools-visit-poppy-choice_-pupils-from-london-city-academy.jpg" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" onclick="change(this)" /> Images off!
```